# How to make the content of a scrollview be the scrollview's bounds size

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a form on one of my pages in my app.

The form is enclosed with a scrollview , the content of the form (originally made 320x568 in size) is now sitting in a frame of 320x408

now, if i put the same view in this frame without the scrollview, all of it contents shrinks (the spaces between the views shrink, and the entire thing fits and works in the given frame).

Now, i wanted to make this form responsive to the keyboard, meaning when the keyboard showed on the screen, i wanted to scroll some of the views above the keyboard. So i thought i'd enclose them inside a scrollview

I added the scrollview to the viewcontroller's screen, and put all the views inside with the exact same constraints.

However, the content of the scrollview does not seem to adjust to the fact that the content size is now 320x408 instead of 320x568, and so some of the screen is out of view, and needing to scroll up to see it.

How do i make it so i don't need to scroll up, if the keyboard is not present ?

Comment: Do you want to move up UIView position so that other user can see what he enters in UITextField when the keyboard is present?

Comment: not exactly, i want to make this uitextfield at the top of the screen, rather than "a little above the keyboard"

Comment: set content size for scrollview

Comment: i did that, that doesnt work

Comment: do you want to up the view as you likes when keyboard comes?

Comment: for starters i don't want to up anything, i want the entire view to be visible on the screen, and its not

Comment: I want to reuse the superview , i don't want to guess that any of the views are outside of their bounds